# NullReferenceException when running query in Vici CoolStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, coolstorage, vici

Here is my code :

```
BookMark[] st = CSDatabase.RunQuery<BookMark>(
            @"SELECT * FROM Bookmark WHERE link='" + link + "'");

class BookMark
{
    public string link;
}
```

Sometimes I get a NullReferenceException but I don't why.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a sqlite Database the problem is due to the sqlite database set to an encoding other than UTF-8. Just create a new sqlite database in the UTF-8 encoding and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You've given us almost nothing to go by.  I'd guess you get the exception because the `link` variable in your code is `null`.